# Join Columns of two ActiveRecord Results

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have the following problem:

I want to fetch very specific data from the database which would need a very complex and long SQL statement.

In order to reduce the amount of complexity and improve the reusability of my queries, my idea is to run several statements. Then I want to join the output afterwards.

The resulting relations of my queries look like this:

- user_id, last_access
- user_id, number_of_projects
- user_id, ...

My question is: How can I combine these results to one relation in ActiveRecord or using different methods?

I want it to look like this:

- user_id, last_access, number_of_projects, ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, try has_many ... , through: ...

[see this doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! However, I do not want to simply join relations using has_many, through. I want to take the results that I have (there are a lot of queries) and combine the **results**. At the moment I am converting the results into hashes and merge those hashes which is not a very elegant solution...